# When binding with jQuery, DOM changes aren't reflected in real time

Tags: jquery, dom, user-interface

I'm having a hard time understanding why I cannot update the DOM while jQuery is executing code. This isn't my actual scenareo, but I think it exemplfies the issue I'm having.

I have a button called btnSubmit. When the user clicks it, I want to display a div element that tells the user some processing is happening. Here is the code:

```
$("#btnSubmit").bind("click",
    function () {
        $('#divProcessing').addClass('showProcessing');
        <processing goes here>
        debugger;
    });
```

The processing may or may not require an AJAX call.

Here's my quandry: if I allow my script to break on the debugger statement, the page in the browser isn't updated. Its not updated until the script has finished running.

I've seen many examples about how to do this (using .ajaxStart etc...), however none of them work for me. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Its not updated until the script has finished running." you mean the class is not added ?

Comment: if your process is an ajax that stands for asynchronous you must add the divs class inside it. If not you just put it at the end of your code.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code, at the moment it seems like the problem is in the `<processing goes here>` code block that we can't see.

Comment: ManseUK, yes I mean the class is not added. Thanks!

Comment: Jasper, the issue isn't with the processing. With or without the processing the applied class isn't reflected in the browser until the script has finished running. I've omitted the processing as I think it would add noise to the problem.

Comment: Have a look at this -> http://jsfiddle.net/ggYZM/ works perfectly fine for me .... using setTimeout .... can you please include a) your other code ... b) your CSS ... c) what you expect to happen when the class is applied

Comment: If you removed the <processing goes here> code does the expected happen ? ie to confirm that your CSS is working fine ...

Comment: Are you using IE to test this?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is single-threaded by design. When you update an element in the DOM, it will get updated in memory so you can access the updates in further JavaScript code. However the browser display itself will not get updated until the script has finished and execution is passed back to the browser window.

Using setTimeout works because it releases execution once the click function is finished and the browser has a chance to update the page before the function passed to setTimeout is called.

By putting the `debugger;` statement in the click function, you never give the browser window a chance to update before execution is halted in the debugger.

You could put an `alert();` statement directly before the `debugger;` statement. By opening an alert window, JavaScript execution is halted and execution is passed back to the browser until the alert is closed.

**UPDATE:**
Firefox and Chrome will update the page when execution is halted for the debugger. Internet Explorer will not.

Comment: chawkinsuf, thanks! However, I don't want to defer execution which is what setTimeout does. I'd like my DOM changes to be reflected as the statements are executed.

Comment: It is not possible to see the changes on the page until after the currently executing functions have finished and execution is sent back to the browser window.

Comment: @chawkinsuf if there was an alert after the addClass() function call would that prevent the class from being added and the browser updating ? (until the alert is OK'd)

Comment: If you use the jsfiddle in my answer and use Chrome debugger to break on the alert - the class change is immediate - the browser is stalled - but the class change still happens

Comment: @ManseUK An alert would actually work since JavaScript execution would stop until the alert is closed, giving the browser a chance to update the page. This prompted me to run a couple quick tests and it seems that FireFox and Chrome will update the page when debugger is called, however Internet Explorer does not (I'm not surprised).

Comment: @chawkinsuf nothing in IE surprises me - i guess we need to see what the OP has in his <processing goes here> block

Answer (score 0):

I have created the follwing in http://jsfiddle.net/ggYZM/4/

```
$("#btnSubmit").bind("click", function() {
    console.log("running");
    $('#mydiv').addClass('showProcessing');
    alert("here"); // blocks the browser
    setTimeout(doneProcessing, 5000);

});

function doneProcessing() {
    $('#mydiv').removeClass('showProcessing');
    console.log('finished');
}

<div id="mydiv"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Click Me!" />

#mydiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
}

.showProcessing {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

It functions exactly as expected - the class is added immediately and the change is clearly visible behind the alert box ... something else must be wrong with your implementation ... perhaps the CSS is not correct ?

Answer (score -1):

Try .show(). Or just make the div a dialog and use $("#divid").dialog("open");

Comment: I user this in a couple places. When a modal changes the value of a control on the main page, this comes in handy as well. http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Per the docs, `.change()` will fire the change event, which "is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements." So no, I don't think `.change()` will do what you think it does.

Comment: .show() or just make the div a dialog and use $("#divid").dialog("open");

Comment: Nicky B, I'm familiar with the .change() function. I'm inclined to agree with Joe White. Thanks!

Comment: @NickyB the change function (without arguments) causes the change event to be triggered ... this will do nothing on a div ....

Comment: Yeah I'm gathering that from the comments. That is why i suggested the show and the dialog option

Comment: NickyB, show() would give the same behaviour. With show, jQuery sets display: inline. However this change wouldn't be reflected until the javascript finishes running. Thanks!